# Is it possible to override the DebuggerBrowsable attribute

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

The DebuggerBrowsableAttribute was applied to a lot of the properties of some third party library class i am using. However, debugging would be somewhat easier if some of these properties (the public ones) were visible. Is it possible to override the attribute during a debug session?

I found several questions/answers concerning the use of the attribute, but none answering my question.

I am currently using Visual Studio 2019 Community edition.

Comment: I guess you could try using reflection to reach out to the `DebuggerBrowsableAttribute` instance on a member and switch its `State` property to whatever you want.

Comment: You could have a try this class: [Attribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @Crono I tried some things with reflection, but i can't get it to work. Setting the `State` property requires additional reflection, since the property is read-only. But doing so does not result in the desired result.

Comment: @J.Molenkamp I see. Perhaps there's a way to extend the debug visualizer in Visual Studio. I never tried this myself but if I'd want so bad to look at these property values during debugging then this is where I would look next.

Comment: @Crono Thanks for your response. It is not that big of a deal, it would just make my life a little bit easier. Several public properties which i use are hidden in the watch windows, which is somewhat unfortunate.

Comment: Did you have a try DebuggerBrowsable which is like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute?view=vs-2019

Comment: @DylanZhu-MSFT What is it that you want me to try?